# How to pull C comments out of HTML using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import os.path
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url= raw_input('Please enter a URL to an HTML doc or File Path to a saved HTML doc for analysis: ')
if os.path.isfile(url) == False:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    comments = soup1.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, '/* '))
    for c in comments:
        print c
        print "==========="
        #c.decompose()
```

This program will pull all comments out of an HTML file if given the URL of the website intended. Now I know Beautiful Soup says to use tuples only when considering what to pull out, but exactly how would I pull all instances of `/*` out of the file?

Comment: This program won't work at all because the opening quote of the `raw_input` argument is missing.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think it just looked like that the way the code was presented. Fixed in on screen.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I fixed it now.

Comment: Could you provide an example document? What do you mean by *"says to use tuples only"*? What results do you get instead of what you were hoping?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think I got it wokring. If you want to see what I changed I Can send you it, but I think the way I was trying to go about it was inherently flawed.

Comment: If you think it might be useful for others in the future, you are free to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sure thing.